# Getting Started with Openshift using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, openshift-origin

I wanted to stand up a local instance of Openshift, but `vagrant up` doesn't finish.

I downloaded `cdk-2.2.0.zip` and `rhel-cdk-kubernetes-7.2-29.x86_64.vagrant-virtualbox.box` from developers.redhat.com.

Running `vagrant up` after installation gets stuck at `Configuring and enabling network interfaces...`:

```
me:~/cdk/components/rhel/rhel-ose $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'cdkv2'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: rhel-ose_default_1476736433516_4922
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Registering box with vagrant-registration...
    default: Would you like to register the system now (default: yes)? [y|n]y
    default: username: me@email.com
    default: password: 
==> default: Registration successful.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: No guest additions were detected on the base box for this VM! Guest
    default: additions are required for forwarded ports, shared folders, host only
    default: networking, and more. If SSH fails on this machine, please install
    default: the guest additions and repackage the box to continue.
    default: 
    default: This is not an error message; everything may continue to work properly,
    default: in which case you may ignore this message.
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?  Not sure if it's vagrant or the VM or something else.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same happened to me but after updating Vagrant to 1.9.1 version the problem was solved.

I am using OSX but it might be the same for all others OS.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I'll give that a try the next time.

Comment: Just tried out 1.9.1 and it works. Thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 0):

the easiest is to install the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) and let it install and configure the Virtual Box Guest Addition for the right version of your VirtualBox

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the plugin didn't work.  Did you have to do something special to get vagrant working with SSH during the vagrant installation?